# How to do an INNER JOIN for a one-to-many where the many should only return one

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query

```
SELECT  p.productId,
        p.productTitle,
        p.productPrice1,
        p.productPrice2,
        p.productPart,
        pi.productImageTitle,
        pi.productImageDescription,
        pi.productImageFile,
        pi.productImageOrder
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN productImage AS pi
    ON p.productId = pi.productId
ORDER BY p.productId ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle with test data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6346b/4)

What i want are all the products, regardless if they have an image or not but if there is a joined image i only want to get one. currently with *product b* it will return 4 rows as there are 4 images.

i did try doing a [sub `SELECT` in the `INNER JOIN` with `LIMIT 1`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6346b/5) but that only allowed one image to be joined. also as you can see with the data `productImageOrder` doesn't always start at one so i can't just filter non 1's in the `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Have you tried doing group by?

Comment: @Zymus \*faceplam\* that's right, the `GROUP BY` will also group the results of the INNER JOIN. i kept thinking it would only apply to the first table and not to the second. just tried it in my sql fiddle and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Adding a GROUP BY for the product should do it

```
SELECT  p.productId,
    p.productTitle,
    p.productPrice1,
    p.productPrice2,
    p.productPart,
    pi.productImageTitle,
    pi.productImageDescription,
    pi.productImageFile,
    pi.productImageOrder
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN productImage AS pi
ON p.productId = pi.productId
GROUP BY p.productId
ORDER BY p.productId ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT  p.productId,
        p.productTitle,
        p.productPrice1,
        p.productPrice2,
        p.productPart,
        pi.productImageTitle,
        pi.productImageDescription,
        pi.productImageFile,
        pi.productImageOrder
FROM product AS p
LEFT JOIN productImage AS pi
    ON p.productId = pi.productId
GROUP BY p.productId
ORDER BY p.productId ASC
```

essentially just adding a `GROUP BY` clause.

Be advised, that this is a MySQLism - other RDBMS will throw a "Invalid use of aggregate" or similar error.

Answer (score 0):

How about using using a select to get the productImageID to join to

```
SELECT  p.productId,
            p.productTitle,
            p.productPrice1,
            p.productPrice2,
            p.productPart,
            pi.productImageTitle,
            pi.productImageDescription,
            pi.productImageFile,
            pi.productImageOrder


    FROM product AS p
    LEFT JOIN productImage AS pi
        ON pi.productImageID = (select productImageId from productImage as pi2 where p.productId = pi2.productId order by productImageOrder Limit 1)
    ORDER BY p.productId ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6346b/13)

This method might actually work on other RDBMS where you can't use an GROUP BY if you haven't put the other fields in an aggregate function, e.g. MIN, MAX, SUM etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the outer aggregation, you can use a join:

```
select p.*, pi.*
from (select p.*,
             (select pi.productImageId
              from productImage pi
              where p.productId = pi.productId
             ) as productImageId
      from product p
     ) p join
     productImage pi
     on p.productImageId = pi.productImageId
order by p.productId;
```

The three advantages of this approach are:

1. Materializing the subquery is probably faster than doing an aggregation.
2. You have more control over which image you take (use an `order by` in the correlated subquery).
3. This is standard SQL and not using any MySQL extensions.

You do want indexes on `productImage(productId)` and `productImage(productImageId)` for best performance.